# Python Fasta Parser using dictionaries without using BioPython or other external libraries

Tags: python, parsing, homework, bioinformatics

I am writing my own parser for fasta format. I can't use Biopython or anything else, because it's a part of an assigment and our teacher wants us to try to do it manually.
For now, I have done this:

```
def read_file(fasta_file):
    "Parse fasta file"
    count = 0
    headers = []
    sequences = []
    aux = []
    with open("yeast.fna", 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            record = line.rstrip()
            if record and record[0] == '>':
                headers.append(record[1:])
                if count > 0:
                    sequences.append(''.join(aux))
                    aux = []
            else:
                aux.append(record)
            count += 1

    sequences.append(''.join(aux))
    return headers, sequences

headers, sequences = read_file("yeast.fna")
lengths = 0
countN = 0
acum = 0
lengths = []
n = 0

lengths = [len(entry) for entry in sequences]
count = sum(lengths)


seqlengths = [entry for entry in sequences]
countN = [entry.count("N") + entry.count("n") for entry in sequences]



print("\nTotal length of the assembly : ", count)
print("\n Total number of unsequenced nucleotides (Ns) in the assembly : ", countN)

#arrange the secq sizes in decrossing order
all_len = sorted(lengths, reverse=True)
print(all_len)

#Search for size accumulation until the size is <= half the size
for y in range (len(lengths)):
    if acum <= count/2:
        acum = all_len[y] + acum
        n = y #L50

n = n + 1 # because the vector begin by a 0
print("The L50 is", n)
print("The N50 is", all_len[n-1]) #Seq is n-1 because vector begin in 0
```

As you can see this parser does some basic stats like calculating L50, ... But the problem with this parser is that it is not very universal since I designed it for the assembled genome of S. Cerivisae which has 17 chromosomes. I know that the best way to do a universal effective parser is to use a dictionary (and make 2 dictionaries).

Can you help me with that?

---

Here is a sample of input file `yeast.fna`. It is basically a txt file with headers which begin by a `>` followed by the dna sequences. I just copy part of it because it's a very big txt file with 17 chromosomes sequences (each one has it own header).

```
>NC_001133.9 Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288C chromosome I, complete sequence
ccacaccacacccacacacccacacaccacaccacacaccacaccacacccacacacacacatCCTAACACTACCCTAAC
ACAGCCCTAATCTAACCCTGGCCAACCTGTCTCTCAACTTACCCTCCATTACCCTGCCTCCACTCGTTACCCTGTCCCAT
TCAACCATACCACTCCGAACCACCATCCATCCCTCTACTTACTACCACTCACCCACCGTTACCCTCCAATTACCCATATC
>NC_001134.8 Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288C chromosome II, complete sequence
AAATAGCCCTCATGTACGTCTCCTCCAAGCCCTGTTGTCTCTTACCCGGATGTTCAACCAAAAGCTACTTACtaccttta
ttttatgtttactttttatagGTTGTCTTTTTATCCCACTTCTTCGCACTTGTCTCTCGCTACTGCCGTGCAACAAACAC
TAAATcaaaacaatgaaataCTACTACATCAAAACGCATTTTccctagaaaaaaaattttcttacAATATACTATACTAC
ACAATACATAATCACTGACTTTCgtaacaacaatttccttcacTCTCCAACTTCTCTGCTCGAATCTCTACatagtaata
>NC_001148.4 Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288C chromosome XVI, complete sequence
AAATAGCCCTCATGTACGTCTCCTCCAAGCCCTGTTGTCTCTTACCCGGATGTTCAACCAAAAGCTACTTACtaccttta
ttttatgtttactttttatagaTTGTCTTTTTATCCTACTCTTTCCCACTTGTCTCTCGCTACTGCCGTGCAACAAACAC
TAAATCAAAACAGTGAAATACTACTACATCAAAACGCATATTccctagaaaaaaaaatttcttacaATATACTATACTAC
```

Here is my output when I run my code :

```
Total length of the assembly :  12157105

 Total number of unsequenced nucleotides (Ns) in the assembly :  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1531933, 1091291, 1090940, 1078177, 948066, 924431, 813184, 784333, 745751, 666816, 576874, 562643, 439888, 316620, 270161, 230218, 85779]
The L50 is 6
The N50 is 924431
```

Everything is okay but I need to make a more universal fasta parser which doesn't work only for my specific input file with 17 chromosome. In order to do that I have to use dictionary but I really don't know how to do that.
You can also download the [full input file](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/15?genome_assembly_id=22535).
At the top of the page in line "Download sequences in FASTA format for genome, transcript, protein" you click on "genome" and you will download the file which is zipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `read_file` returns headers and sequences implicitly correlated by their order. A model that is easier to work with is to make sequence class instances that each have their own header and sequence string.

If you accept `fasta_file`, then why do you hard-code `yeast.fna`?

`yeast.fna`'s original name is `GCF_000146045.2_R64_genomic.fna`. It seems unwise to discard this information, unless perhaps `yeast.fna` is a symlink.

This code is not just a parser - it does a little bit of analysis. Ensure that your parsing code and analysis code are separated, and that neither leaks into the global namespace.

Separate your summary calculation from your summary printing.

As to your concern that

> it is not very universal since I designed it for the assembled genome of S. Cerivisae which has 17 chromosomes.

I don't see where you've hard-coded 17 chromosomes, so (apart from other design concerns) this doesn't seem like a problem.

> I know that the best way to do a universal effective parser is to use a dictionary (and make 2 dictionaries).

I don't think so. Prefer class instances rather than dictionaries for internal data.

Consider making two lightweight classes - one for each sequence, and one for the assembly overall.

You should do some basic parsing of your header - the first field is the ID, and the rest of the string is the description.

I have validity concerns about the way that you measure unsequenced data. Part of the problem seems to be with the format itself, but part of the problem looks to be with your parser, because it doesn't pay attention to `X` or `-`.

Consider using Python's built-in `gzip` support and operating on that archive directly rather than decompressing it on the file system.

Introduce PEP484 type hinting to your code.

You have descriptive headings for almost all of your summary fields - good! Add one for your `all_len`.

### Suggested

This suggested code exclusively uses modules that are built into Python 3.9.

```py
import gzip
from io import StringIO
from itertools import accumulate
from typing import Iterator, NamedTuple, Optional, Tuple


class FastaSequence(NamedTuple):
    identifier: str
    description: str
    sequence: str

    @staticmethod
    def parse_lines(lines: Iterator[str]) -> Tuple[
        str,            # sequence
        Optional[str],  # next header
    ]:
        next_header: Optional[str] = None

        def iterate():
            nonlocal next_header
            for line in lines:
                line = line.rstrip()
                if line.startswith('>'):
                    next_header = line
                    break
                yield line

        return ''.join(iterate()), next_header

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, in_file: Iterator[str]) -> Iterator['FastaSequence']:
        header = next(in_file).rstrip()
        while True:
            identifier, description = header[1:].split(maxsplit=1)
            sequence, next_header = cls.parse_lines(in_file)
            yield cls(identifier, description, sequence)
            if next_header is None:
                break
            header = next_header

    @property
    def n_unsequenced(self) -> int:
        # This is problematic and probably wrong, because documentation like
        # http://genetics.bwh.harvard.edu/pph/FASTA.html
        # says that X or - could also indicate unsequenced data, and N might
        # also just mean 'asparagine'.
        # - in particular indicates that this count is only a lower bound as the
        # gap is of indeterminate length.
        return sum(
            1 for x in self.sequence
            if x.lower() in {'n', 'x', '-'}
        )


class FastaAssembly:
    def __init__(self, sequences: Tuple[FastaSequence]) -> None:
        self.sequences = sequences
        
        self.sequence_lengths = sorted(
            (len(seq.sequence) for seq in self.sequences),
            reverse=True,
        )
        self.length = sum(self.sequence_lengths)
        index_50 = self.half_length
        self.l50 = index_50 + 1
        self.n50 = self.sequence_lengths[index_50]

    @property
    def half_length(self) -> int:
        for i, total in enumerate(accumulate(self.sequence_lengths)):
            if total > self.length/2:
                return i
        raise IndexError()  # This will never happen

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, in_file: Iterator[str]) -> 'FastaAssembly':
        return cls(tuple(FastaSequence.from_file(in_file)))

    @property
    def summary(self) -> str:
        unsequenced = [seq.n_unsequenced for seq in self.sequences]
        return (
            f'Total length of the assembly: {self.length}'
            f'\nTotal number of unsequenced nucleotides (Ns) in the assembly: {unsequenced}'
            f'\nAll sequence lengths: {self.sequence_lengths}'
            f'\nThe L50 is {self.l50}'
            f'\nThe N50 is {self.n50}'
        )


EXAMPLE = \
'''>NC_001133.9 Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288C chromosome I, complete sequence
ccacaccacacccacacacccacacaccacaccacacaccacaccacacccacacacacacatCCTAACACTACCCTAAC
ACAGCCCTAATCTAACCCTGGCCAACCTGTCTCTCAACTTACCCTCCATTACCCTGCCTCCACTCGTTACCCTGTCCCAT
TCAACCATACCACTCCGAACCACCATCCATCCCTCTACTTACTACCACTCACCCACCGTTACCCTCCAATTACCCATATC
>NC_001134.8 Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288C chromosome II, complete sequence
AAATAGCCCTCATGTACGTCTCCTCCAAGCCCTGTTGTCTCTTACCCGGATGTTCAACCAAAAGCTACTTACtaccttta
ttttatgtttactttttatagGTTGTCTTTTTATCCCACTTCTTCGCACTTGTCTCTCGCTACTGCCGTGCAACAAACAC
TAAATcaaaacaatgaaataCTACTACATCAAAACGCATTTTccctagaaaaaaaattttcttacAATATACTATACTAC
ACAATACATAATCACTGACTTTCgtaacaacaatttccttcacTCTCCAACTTCTCTGCTCGAATCTCTACatagtaata
>NC_001148.4 Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288C chromosome XVI, complete sequence
AAATAGCCCTCATGTACGTCTCCTCCAAGCCCTGTTGTCTCTTACCCGGATGTTCAACCAAAAGCTACTTACtaccttta
ttttatgtttactttttatagaTTGTCTTTTTATCCTACTCTTTCCCACTTGTCTCTCGCTACTGCCGTGCAACAAACAC
TAAATCAAAACAGTGAAATACTACTACATCAAAACGCATATTccctagaaaaaaaaatttcttacaATATACTATACTAC
'''


def test() -> None:
    with StringIO(EXAMPLE) as f:
        assembly = FastaAssembly.from_file(f)
        print(assembly.summary)
    print()

    with gzip.open('GCF_000146045.2_R64_genomic.fna.gz', 'rt') as f:
        assembly = FastaAssembly.from_file(f)
        print(assembly.summary)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

### Output

```
Total length of the assembly: 800
Total number of unsequenced nucleotides (Ns) in the assembly: [0, 0, 0]
All sequence lengths: [320, 240, 240]
The L50 is 2
The N50 is 240

Total length of the assembly: 12157105
Total number of unsequenced nucleotides (Ns) in the assembly: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
All sequence lengths: [1531933, 1091291, 1090940, 1078177, 948066, 924431, 813184, 784333, 745751, 666816, 576874, 562643, 439888, 316620, 270161, 230218, 85779]
The L50 is 6
The N50 is 924431
```

Comment: may i ask why you used `NamedTuple` instead of dataclasses ? Is it just for unpacking namedtuples or it has more advantages in this case? Thanks!!

Comment: @AlexDotis Named tuples are naturally immutable and have a simpler API than dataclasses.